Help finding LDO IC with marking on device: 5ZCO
IC marking: 5ZCO
The package is HSOP-6, a very strange package.
It seems it is an LDO.


As indicated yesterday, providing a picture can be helpful.

Fanglian WANG - Hi, When asking component identification questions, please follow the steps given in this meta post: Component Identification Question Guidelines. Therefore please [edit] this question to add the missing information explained in that linked article. While editing and after adding that information, mark/tick the "Submit for review" checkbox before clicking the "Save edits" button. Then wait for the question to be reviewed. TY

Thanks, I have added the picture, the package is sot-23-5,

@FanglianWANG - I have reopened the question. The details in the updated question are only the bare minimum e.g. there is no explanation of the surrounding circuit, nor details of what device that PCB came from, nor a wider photo of the whole PCB to give some context. FYI identification questions are improved when details like that are provided. TY (I don't know why your comment says the package is SOT-23-5 when the question states something different and it looks like a 6-pin package in the photo.)

Since it's connected to the VCC pin of a Chinese brand CAN transceiver. It's likely a Chinese 5V LDO, but I can't find anyone using this package besides Ablic and Nisshinbo.

As mentionned in the comments above. This is most likely a LDO regulator manufactured by ABLIC.
Marking description for the HSOP6 package:

Sometimes there are slight differences (p27):

Futhermore I found a very similar marking here and here (Taobao).

But the problem is how to find the designation.
This is a problem that i have encountered previously and not solved. Unfortunately many of their datasheets do not provide the marking code. (example in this thread).
Nonetheless the common point of these LDO regulators in this package from ABLIC is that the pin n°1 (bottom left) is the output voltage.
If the component is alive maybe you could check the voltage then to confirm the hypothesis made by @nanash1 in the comments. (5V to supply the CAN transceiver). But for the exact designation you will probably need to inquire directly to ABLIC customer service.
